# Как правильно типизировать глубоко вложенные объекты?

Tags: typescript

Я хочу что бы в зависимости от `tagName` подбирался правильно тип элемента. Сейчас все работает как нужно пока не начинаю добавлять `children`.

```
export interface ElementCreatorParameters<T extends keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap > {
  tagName: T
  children?: Array<ElementCreatorParameters<T>>
  onCreate?(element: HTMLElementTagNameMap[T]): void
}

export class ElementCreator<T extends keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap > {
  constructor(parameters: ElementCreatorParameters<T>) {}
}

new ElementCreator({
  tagName: 'form',
  onCreate: (element) => {
    // Должно быть HTMLFormElement
    // Сейчас HTMLFormElement | HTMLInputElement
    element
  },
  children: [
    {
      tagName: 'input',
      onCreate: (element) => {
        // Должно быть HTMLInputElement
        // Сейчас HTMLFormElement | HTMLInputElement
        element
      },
    },
  ],
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша задача показалась мне очень интересной. Но признаться честно, я не смог сам её решить, потому задал похожий [вопрос на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76168746/declare-type-where-type-of-one-field-based-on-value-of-another-field). Из того что сам нагуглил я понял что `interface`-ами его не решить, нужны `type`-ы, потому в самом вопросе сразу написал с типами. [Автор](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz) ответа тоже подтвердил, что с помощью `interface`-ов это не решить

Мой ответ - перевод [ответа на мой вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76174678/13349770). Потому не забывайте ставить плюсики оригинальному ответу тоже :)

---

Вы можете представить `ElementCreatorParameters` как [объеденённый тип (union type)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types), где каждый элемент в объединении соответсвует одному из значений `tagName` из `keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap`. Конечно, элементов в объединении может быть больше 100, а потому писать это всё вручную очень нудно, но т.к. их количесвто конечно, то объединение - по крайней мере возможное решение. К счастью, нам не нужно все элементы объединения расписывать вручную, вместо этого мы можем заставить компилятор сгенерировать их для нас. Например так:

```ts
type ElementCreatorParameters = { [K in keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap]: {
  tagName: K
  children?: Array<ElementCreatorParameters>
  onCreate?(element: HTMLElementTagNameMap[K]): void
}}[keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap]
```

Основная идея заключается в том, чтобы создать [сопоставленный тип (mapped type)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html), а затем [проиндексировать](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) его со всеми его ключами, чтобы получить объединение свойств сопоставленного типа. Это можно назвать *дистрибутивным типом объекта*, как указано в [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109). Если у вас есть набор ключей `type KK = K1 | K2 | K3 | ⋯` , тогда `{[K in KK]: F<K>}[KK]` преобразуется в `F<K1> | F<K2> | F<K3> | ⋯`

В нашем случае, `KK` - это `keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap`, а `F<K>` - это

```ts
{
  tagName: K
  children?: Array<ElementCreatorParameters>
  onCreate?(element: HTMLElementTagNameMap[K]): void
}
```

Таким образом `ElementCreatorParameters` - это большое объединение, которое вы можете увидеть если наведёте мышку для получения быстрой информации в вашем `IntelliSense-enabled IDE`:

```ts
/* type ElementCreatorParameters = {
  tagName: "object";
  children?: ElementCreatorParameters[] | undefined;
  onCreate?(element: HTMLObjectElement): void;
} | {
  tagName: "a";
  children?: ElementCreatorParameters[] | undefined;
  onCreate?(element: HTMLAnchorElement): void;
} | ... 108 more ... | {
    ...;
} */
```

---

Давайте протестируем это:

```
const e: ElementCreatorParameters = {
  tagName: 'form',
  onCreate: (element) => {
    element // (parameter) element: HTMLFormElement
  },
  children: [
    {
      tagName: 'input',
      onCreate: (element) => {
        element // (parameter) element: HTMLInputElement
      },
      children: [
        {
          tagName: 'a',
          onCreate: (element) => {
            element // (parameter) element: HTMLAnchorElement
          },
        },
      ]
    },
  ],
}
```

Выглядит превосходно! Все параметры `onCreate` выводятся контекстуально из соответствующего элемента объединения `ElementCreatorParameters` по желанию

[Ссылка на Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogNhAthAdsAwgJwgQ2Ae0wAUdMdlgJMBnKAXigG8oBtAaSgEsUoBrCEPgBmUABIAVALIAZeElTBxOAOYA5chEk4wAXQBcTAFBQowFeuQG2xqAGMAFpzgATbCgD8BgIKYyIADxyyGhYuATEpBqUNAB8NvgooXgQ7gAUEAjBwAYSMkEKSmoaWmDsOgCUBgBu+JzOhgC+UA0s-IIiubKZBebF2jqGhrYJ1MBQEAb5Idh4hCRkFFS0DIw2ZkWWUADkQoSIWwA08YkzlAbp3Wjl9DFGJiYZ8mhQAPQvUKlgkYuY149ZOSk0gAYnspsAbA0jiYHE5XKgDCwbCZVvd7usLBNttwwABXYCHZH3BJJM4ff4Ka50W6otH3CnPN4fL4LCDRP6XbJiIEASRQeOA4KJJihwrsjhcbkRYpRMvRvU2WxwhLpdJJpyxFyewCpNLlaIZYyZn2+bKoHO1gJkXhQDkIQtVaNFjua0LpAydbp0RwahiAA)

Comment: Спасибо что заинтересовались )